# Sequential drawing of lines and points

Tags: qgis, network, geopackage, graph

It is required to draw different geometry types alternately. Like this: point - line - point - line - point - ...

Is there any way in QGIS that provides users with such features:

- drawing objects of different types "on the fly" (with a minimum of unnecessary actions for switching between layers)
- binding objects to each other.

*Implementation example*

As an example ZuluGIS has a very handy editor for creating a connected network from objects of different types - see https://youtu.be/6EeQ6zi7jPs?t=132.

*Description of scenarios*

The QGIS project must have vector layers with geometry types:

1. Line
2. Point

There can be one or several such layers.

Scenario #1 (basic, drawing objects without reference to those already on the map):

1. The user selects Toggle Editing and Add Line Feature for any of the line layers.
2. The user double-clicks on the map to draw the starting point of the line.
3. QGIS opens a dialog box with a list of all the point layers of the project.
4. The user selects any point layer from the list.
5. QGIS draws simultaneously:

- the object of the selected point layer;
- the starting point of the line
  In this case, all coordinates of the object of the selected point layer and the starting point of the line must be equal to (X, Y, Z)

6. The user double-clicks on another place on the map to draw the end point of the line.
7. QGIS opens a dialog box with a list of all the point layers of the project.
8. The user selects any point layer from the list.
9. QGIS draws simultaneously:

- the object of the selected point layer;
- the line between the start and end points
  In this case, all coordinates of the object of the selected point layer and the end point of the line must be equal to (X, Y, Z)

Alternative scenarios (not exhaustive):

Scenario #2 (drawing with reference to already existing point objects):

1. Or:

- step 1 of scenario #1 has been completed;
- step 3 of scenario #2 has been completed.

2. The user presses Ctrl and double-clicks on any previously drawn point object on the map to draw the start or end point of the line.
3. QGIS draws the starting or ending point of the line in the same place where the point object closest to the click point is located.
   At the same time, if there are no point objects within a radius of 1 m, then paragraphs 3 - 5 of scenario No. 1 are executed.

Scenario #3 (standard operations):

1. When drawing a line, the user makes one click on the map.
2. QGIS does standard operations.

Scenario #4 (disconnecting a line from one point object and then attaching it to another point object)

Scenario #5 (replacing a previously drawn point object with another one)

Scenario #6 (Topological Editing for a drawn network)

*PS (possible solutions)*

1. The format of ZuluGIS layers is a bit similar to Geopakage, as contains various graphic object types and optionally can use SQLite to store attributes.
2. Connected lines and points can be represented as graphs.

Comment: I am pretty sure what you need can be done with the Geometry Generator in Layer Styles (it can dynamically generate rendering for data from one/multiple layers). To get more specific help, you should probably provide more details about your data, the expected result and what you have tried

Comment: @Kasper I added the Description of scenarios section to the description. I hope it has become clearer